# How can I automatically retrain the model created by the Azure Automated ML

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Scenario: I've used Automated ML to pick the best model for me. Great!

But my dataset will grow over time as we collect more data. Now I'd like to auto-schedule a job to retrain that model once a month, for example. How can I do that?

I understand I can create a training pipeline and schedule that pipeline job. But, the Automated ML process doesn't seem to produce any pipeline that I can view in the Designer UI. I don't see any way to schedule the training job that Automated ML has created.

As an aside, if I manually create a training pipeline for my dataset in the UI, and then run it to train a model myself using linear regression, the resulting model isn't nearly as accurate as what the Automated ML process is producing for me. I'm not sure why that is. The Automated ML process picks VotingEnsemble as the best algorithm, but I don't have the option, seemingly, to use that algorithm in the pipeline designer.

I've gone through as much documentation as I can for Automated ML and numerous tutorials but am unable to find the answer.

I've tried creating a training pipeline in the Designer, but the resulting model isn't accurate.

Comment: There is a Azure Machine Learning SDK in Python. You can create pipelines and AutoML with it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ml/install?view=azure-ml-py. Note that it has learning curve but you gain more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the automated ML process doesn't currently produce a training pipeline that can view in the Designer UI. This might be by design itself as the AutoML process is designed to be a black box to make it more user friendly.

One possible alternate can be to use Azure ML Python SDK that can provide functionality to create AutoML training job and scheduler as per requirement.

You can refer to this sample [notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/continuous-retraining/auto-ml-continuous-retraining.ipynb) that demonstrate the continues retraining of a regression model with Auto ML Step consist of pre-defined auto ml settings and configuration. It captures the best model and matrices at each iteration and registered the updated model.